# C++: Problem with M1 architecture in cmake: how do I change the architecture?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to run cmake command in the new environment.

Upon running `cmake . .` I get `clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=core2'` error. I tried to run it with `cmake '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-march=x86-64''` flag, and it changed the `march` for a while but only in CLion IDE and only when I was doing that continuously. I can't seem to make it work in the terminal while reading different makefile.

Full error when I run either `cmake` or ```cmake '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-march=x86-64'':

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/marcin/CLionProjects/pythontest5/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_925c1/fast && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_925c1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_925c1.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_925c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc   -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/include  -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_925c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_925c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_925c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/marcin/CLionProjects/pythontest5/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=core2'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_925c1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_925c1/fast] Error 2
```

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

project(automobile VERSION 0.1.0)


# Include dir
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

# Src
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(src SRC_FILES)

# Headers
set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR "src")
set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR "include/automobile_bits")

# Source files
set(SOURCE_FILES
    ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}/motorcycle.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/motorcycle.cpp
)

# Set up such that XCode organizes the files correctly
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Add library
add_library(automobile SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Include directories
target_include_directories(automobile PRIVATE include/automobile_bits)

# Install
install(TARGETS automobile DESTINATION lib)

# Install the headers
install(FILES include/automobile DESTINATION include)

# Create base directory
install(DIRECTORY include/automobile_bits DESTINATION include)
```

Comment: Where are you getting your CMake distribution from? Is it built for the M1, or is it built for x86-64 and running through Rosetta 2?

Comment: @jjramsey brew installed via regular fish terminal (not rosetta), so that should be for M1?

Comment: Depends. What do you get when you run `file \`which cmake\``?

Comment: Also, "Rosetta 2" isn't a terminal. It's what allows most x86-64 binaries to run on M1 Macs.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear where `cmake` gets `-march=core2` from. Try to remove CMakeCache.txt then re-run `cmake .`.

If it does not help, try to remove CMakeCache.txt and run `cmake . -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64`.